# How to create a second LoT with other labels?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I have two sets of tables in my document. I was able to label the second type with other name thanks to the following:

```
\DeclareCaptionType{cuad}[Cuadro][Índice de Cuadros Estadísticos]
```

Now I want to add this ones as a LoT with the caption and the number (Cuadro 1: blablabla). But when I use:

```
\listofcuads %índice de cuadros estadísticos
```

I get the following result:
[image: LoC_v1]

So to add the word Cuadro, I used:

```
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\cuadname~\oldnumberline}%
\listofcuads%
}
```

But then I find this problem: (It's not justified as LoF or LoT)
[image: LoC_v2]

I've tried using:

```
\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Cuadro }
\settowidth\mylen{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\mylen}
\setlength\cfttabindent{0pt}
```

Changing the "tab" environment for "cuad". But still, no result.

I would thank you a lot if you can help me!